# Express not setting auth cookie

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, passport.js

I am using PassportJS to authenticate my users via Google Oauth and a local username/password combo. After it all working on my local machine(localhost) I deployed my express server and my NextJS frontend. Then I went to test my login/registration, and my "local" auth via a username/password combo worked just fine. But then I went to test my Google auth and it doesn't work. It opens up the google screen where you select your email, and after selecting my email, I get redirected to my application without the auth cookie being set, i.e. not authenticated. I don't see any errors, and in the logs of my express app I can see it is generating a JWT cookie and setting it, but the frontend never receives it. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```js
public handleGoogleCallback = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        
        const accessToken = generateJWT(req.user);
        logger.info(`Setting cookie '${JWT_COOKIE_NAME}' with value: ${accessToken}`);
        res.cookie(JWT_COOKIE_NAME, accessToken, {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24 * 31, // 31 days
            domain: "myapp.com",
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
        });
        

        return res.redirect(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL.href); // This redirects to myapp.com/
    };
```

Just a note: my frontend app is deployed to `myapp.com`, while the backend is deployed at `api.myapp.com`